# EARs are automatically undeployed in jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

Tags: java, unix, jboss

I am not getting while EARs are undeployed automatically in jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.

I can see these logs:

```
ERROR org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor [run] Socket accept failed: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

WARN com.kpn.tie.ejbs.dao.webservice.tt.WebServiceProcessor [invoke] WebService unavailable. The request could not be completed due to technical problems. ; nested exception is:      java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
```

Can somebody tell me root cause of this behavior and also suggest solution for this.

For workaround, restarting jboss in particular time interval will resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

**The reason** could be that the application is overloaded or the file descriptor settings is too low. Due to this, the `JVM` can not open any new file handle, so you are getting `Socket accept failed` for incoming requests.
After a while the `Deployment-Scanner` comes into play (5 sec is default) and tries to check the deployments folder, which is not possible as it can not open any file-handle. So it gets confused and stops the deployed apps.

**First solution** could be:
Deactivate the scanner so that it only checks once during boot or remove the deployment scanner subsystem and use only `CLI` to deploy.

**Second solution** could be:
Increase the file-handler limit (open files size)

Answer (score 0):

> java.net.SocketException: **Too many open files**

On Linux you can increase the number of concurrently open files with

```
ulimit -n 2048
```

This would allow `2048` open at the same time in the current session. The command should be either inserted in the session configuration (e.g. .bashrc or similar, depends on your used shell) or in the JBoss start script.

To show the current limit you can use

```
ulimit -n
```